# Reserving clean block of identity values in T-SQL for data migration

Tags: sql-server, data-migration, identity-column

We're currently working on the following process whose goal is to move data between 2 sets of database servers while maintaining FK's and handling the fact that the destination tables already have rows with overlapping identity column values:

1. Extract a set of rows from a "root" table and all of its children tables' FK associated data n-levels deep along with related rows that may reside in other databases on the same instance from the source database server.
2. Place that extracted data set into a set of staging tables on the destination database server.
3. Rekey the data in the staging tables by reserving block of identities for the destination tables and update all related child staging tables (each of these staging tables will have the same schema as the source/destination table with the addition of a "lNewIdentityID" column).
4. Insert the data with its new identity into the destination tables in correct order (option SET IDENTITY_INSERT 'desttable' ON will be used obviously).

I'm struggling with the block reservation portion of this process (#3).  Our system is pretty much a 24 hour system except for a short weekly maintenance window.  Management needs this process to NOT have to wait each week for the maintenance window to migrate data between servers.  That being said, I may have 100 insert transactions competing with our migration process while it is on #3.  Below is my wag at an attempt to reserve the block of identities, but I'm worried that between "SET @newIdent..." and "DBCC CHECKIDENT..." that an insert transaction will complete and the migration process won't have a "clean" block of identities in a known range that it can use to rekey the staging data.

I essentially need to lock the table, get the current identity, increase the identity, and then unlock the table.  I don't know how to do that in T-SQL and am looking for ideas.  Thank you.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sys.procedures WHERE [name]='DataMigration_ReserveBlock')
    DROP PROC DataMigration_ReserveBlock
GO

CREATE PROC DataMigration_ReserveBlock (
    @tableName varchar(100), 
    @blockSize int
)
AS
 BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

    DECLARE @newIdent bigint;
    SET @newIdent = @blockSize + IDENT_CURRENT(@tableName);

    DBCC CHECKIDENT (@tableName, RESEED, @newIdent); 

    SELECT @newIdent AS NewIdentity;
 END
GO


DataMigration_ReserveBlock 'tblAddress', 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a transaction

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
...
COMMIT
```

It should be fast enough to not cause problems with your other insert processes.  Though it would be a good idea to include try / catch logic so you could rollback if problems do occur.